# janino compile Java code throws "class could not be found exception"

Tags: java, janino

**Backgroud**

I use `squirrel` state machine and want to generate its relate class(state,event,context,etc.) dynamicly(state might change)

I tried to generate and compile Java code after Springboot application started.
There are four files A,B,C,D.

A,B,C are simple java beans, D extends external lib class.

The example code is shown below:

```
public void testCompile() throws Exception {
        String a = "package roa;\n" +
                    "public enum A{\n" +
                    "  Pass,\n" +
                    "  Refuse;\n" +
                    "}";
        String b = "package roa;\n" +
                    "public enum B{\n" +
                    "  Start,End;\n" +
                    "}";
        String c = "package roa;\n" +
                    "public class C{}";
        String d = "package roa;\n" +
                    "import org.squirrelframework.foundation.fsm.impl.AbstractStateMachine;\n" +
                    "public class D extends AbstractStateMachine<D,A,B,C> {}";

        ICompilerFactory compilerFactory = CompilerFactoryFactory.getDefaultCompilerFactory();
        ICompiler compiler = compilerFactory.newCompiler();
        Map<String, byte[]> classes = Maps.newHashMap();
        compiler.setClassFileCreator(new MapResourceCreator(classes));
        compiler.setClassFileFinder(new MapResourceFinder(classes));
        compiler.compile(new Resource[]{
                new StringResource("roa/A.java", a),
                new StringResource("roa/B.java", b),
                new StringResource("roa/C.java", c),
                new StringResource("roa/D.java", d)
        });
        ClassLoader cl = new ResourceFinderClassLoader(
                new MapResourceFinder(classes),
                ClassLoader.getSystemClassLoader()
        );
        System.out.println(cl.loadClass("roa.A"));
        System.out.println(cl.loadClass("roa.B"));
        System.out.println(cl.loadClass("roa.C"));
        System.out.println(cl.loadClass("roa.D"));
    }
```

It works well in IDE(Intellij IDEA),but won't work when I run it with command `java -jar`.
Exception message is

```
A class "org.squirrelframework.foundation.fsm.impl.AbstractStateMachine" could not be found
```

Version and Dependicies used:

- Java `1.8.0_202` both in IDE and outside
- Springboot `Greenwich.RELEASE`

janino dependency

```
<dependency>
     <groupId>org.codehaus.janino</groupId>
     <artifactId>janino</artifactId>
     <version>3.1.0</version>
</dependency>
```

maven build output

```
zhhang@bogon mvn clean install
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[INFO] 
[INFO] --------------------< com.demo.cloud:oa >---------------------
[INFO] Building oa 1.0-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] --------------------------------[ jar ]---------------------------------
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-clean-plugin:3.1.0:clean (default-clean) @ oa ---
[INFO] Deleting /Users/zhhang/IdeaProjects/inno/oa/target
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-resources-plugin:3.1.0:resources (default-resources) @ oa ---
[INFO] Using 'UTF-8' encoding to copy filtered resources.
[INFO] Copying 1 resource
[INFO] Copying 17 resources
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-compiler-plugin:3.8.0:compile (default-compile) @ oa ---
[INFO] Changes detected - recompiling the module!
[INFO] Compiling 131 source files to /Users/zhhang/IdeaProjects/inno/oa/target/classes
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-resources-plugin:3.1.0:testResources (default-testResources) @ oa ---
[INFO] Using 'UTF-8' encoding to copy filtered resources.
[INFO] skip non existing resourceDirectory /Users/zhhang/IdeaProjects/inno/oa/src/test/resources
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-compiler-plugin:3.8.0:testCompile (default-testCompile) @ oa ---
[INFO] Nothing to compile - all classes are up to date
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-surefire-plugin:2.22.1:test (default-test) @ oa ---
[INFO] Tests are skipped.
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-jar-plugin:3.1.1:jar (default-jar) @ oa ---
[INFO] Building jar: /Users/zhhang/IdeaProjects/inno/oa/target/oa-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- spring-boot-maven-plugin:2.1.4.RELEASE:repackage (repackage) @ oa ---
[INFO] Replacing main artifact with repackaged archive
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-install-plugin:2.5.2:install (default-install) @ oa ---
[INFO] Installing /Users/zhhang/IdeaProjects/inno/oa/target/oa-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar to /Users/zhhang/.m2/repository/com/demo/cloud/oa/1.0-SNAPSHOT/oa-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar
[INFO] Installing /Users/zhhang/IdeaProjects/inno/oa/pom.xml to /Users/zhhang/.m2/repository/com/demo/cloud/oa/1.0-SNAPSHOT/oa-1.0-SNAPSHOT.pom
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD SUCCESS
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time:  9.087 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2020-03-10T10:57:48+08:00
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Besides,I also tried [OpenHFT/Java-Runtime-Compiler](https://github.com/OpenHFT/Java-Runtime-Compiler),works well in IDE and not work run with `java -jar` as well :(

I've searched many questions that similar to mine,but no answer fit me well.
Maybe I use janino in a wrong way,but I dont't know how to fix that.

Any reply is greatly appreciated.

Thank you,Zhhang

Comment: It could be just a dependency problem. Are you creating the jar with any `maven clean install` ?

Make sur your cmd maven version is similar to the one that is used by your IDE.

Comment: Yes, I ceating the jar with ```maven clean install```. Maven version is apache-maven-3.6.0 both in IDE and maven cmd.Also I tried to run the jar installed by IDE, failed again.

Comment: Are JDK version you compile with the same ?

Comment: Can you edit the question with the output of maven build outside the IDE.

Comment: I've add the output of maven build outside.JDK version is the same